# Issue with setting up Telnet Management on Open VPN Server

Tags: openvpn, telnet, virtual-ip

When I enable telnet on openVPN (windows) using this parameter `management localhost 25333`, I am not able to access the clients through their virtual IPs anymore. At the same time, when I disable this parameter `management localhost 25333` in server config, then clients become accessible through virtual IPs but telnet management console is lost.

Please see the attached server and client config file below.

Server Configuration File:

```
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 100.86.0.0 255.255.0.0
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-remote-ip
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log 5
verb 3
port 1194
management localhost 25333
```

Client Configuration File:

```
client 
dev tun
proto tcp
remote my.ovpnserver.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue when run OpenVPN as Service (following the link)
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide#RunningOpenVPNasaService